# How to use Ubuntu App Developer's Key system?

Tags: application-development

Okay so I made a package and submitted it to Ubuntu App Developer. It does not install any files directly, but does depend on Qt framework. The License Key system Ubuntu provides says it will look for it in the specified file. How do I use this system. How do I install a file to that place? What file do I install?

Comment: If you are not installing any files directly what have you packaged?

Comment: ok I worded that wrong. It only installs the actually file, a license, a read-me and the qt libs it needs.

Answer (score 0):

The license key infrastructure system installs a "key file" into a specific location relative to the application binary or in the users home directory depending on how you specify the location. The key file can be anything, but is usually something that your application is looking for to enable the application.

More detail can be found at http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/licence-key-infrastructure/

When a user makes a purchase the key is installed with the package files and alternatively is emailed to the user along with the subscription details.